# "no start line error" при подключении SSL сертификата

Tags: nginx, ssl

Добрый вечер, проблемы с подключением SSL сертификата, в конфиг nginx ввожу следующее:

```
listen     443;
ssl        on;
ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/rak.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/rak.key;
```

Собственно содержимое файлов следующее:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Код соответственно после фразы START CERTIFICATE разный (Я написал так для примере), в каждой строчке по 64 символа, ну кроме последней. Так вот ошибка в следующем, при перезапуске nginx получаю ошибку:

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file("/etc/ssl/rak.pem") failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Так ошибка указывает не на ключ, ключ сделан аналогично сертификату, так же начинается с BEGIN и заканчивается END

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIUb2
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Ключ и сертификат взяты с CloudFlare, созданы мною

Ссылка на инструкцию по созданию SSL сертификата: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000479507

Исходя из этого я получил от них код CERTIFICATE и код PRIVATE KEY, собственно создал два файла: 1) rak.pem (Туда вставил код CERTIFICATE) 2) rak.key (Туда вставил код PRIVATE KEY)

Ссылка на настройку nginx: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217471977

Далее уже описано выше

Comment: а как вы получили это сертификат?

Comment: [дубликат](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609987/178576)?

Answer (score 2):

Директивы у вас верные и делаете по инструкции, а вот с ключом (точнее - с файлом закрытого ключа) что-то не так.

Только ради бога, не выкладывайте в вопрос свой приватный ключ, ладно? :) (Зная пару закрытый ключ - публичный ключ можно подписать любое сообщение от вашего имени)

Приватный ключ, который вы указываете в `ssl_certificate_key` должен начинаться с:

`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`

Судя по описанию ошибки - при такой простой на первый взгляд операции как "вставить текст в файл и сохранить" -- важно, как у вас оформлены переводы строк. Типовые ошибки можно почитать тут (на английском): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837161/openssl-pem-routinespem-read-biono-start-linepem-lib-c703expecting-truste

Поэтому берём какой-нибудь текстовый редактор, который показывает переводы строк (Notepad++, Sublime и т.п.) и внимательно проверяем свои файлы. Например, что файл находится в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM.